# Send push notification with ktor

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, backend, ktor

I made a backend with Ktor framework for a android app and my question is:

How to send push notification from server to phone? What tools could I use for this?

I would like to send notifications that everyone will receive and that just given users will receive.

I am not familiar with Ktor, but my goal with this project is to learn.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

use pusher notification like :

```
 import com.pusher.pushnotifications.PushNotifications;
```

Then register the Device Token at the appropriate point in your application lifecycle and subscribe your device to an interest hello:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PushNotifications.start(getApplicationContext(), "YOUR_INSTANCE_ID");
    PushNotifications.addDeviceInterest("hello");
}
```

it's very convenient if you don't have that much experience

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- Setup your Android app on Firebase [console](https://console.firebase.google.com).

- Get your Server key from Project Settings -> Cloud Messaging -> Server Key
- Get the FCM token from the mobile app and store on server database.
- Trigger the notification on mobile app using the firebase API: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
- Sample for Notification Request: You can use data,notification or both.

  {
  "registration_ids": ["dfYSqZkGTPevi6gHY65F8J:APA91bF9e6vs2BOjgm8yVj3gdS1R_WHQI50I29uEXw01HDbVA1S67i78cBOXy4FubcfvvGerq36WPOuBggdxBZsF_EE0XHa3YSC6MbEDSvOIlQRypLSDhaOjvIiPawOEt7jGF98DjOik"],
  "data": {
  "title": "Hello",
  "body": "User "
  },
  "notificatoin": {
  "title": "Hello",
  "body": "User "
  }
  }